# How can I force an Arduino Leonardo to reset with AVRDUDE?

Tags: arduino

I want to compile and transfer an Arduino program by myself on a Leonardo board.

Everything works great with the Arduino official IDE. I have enabled verbose mode for compiling and bytecode transfer.

I can see each command line. 
I want to understand each line.

Everything is good except last step: transfer with AVRDUDE. If I type exactly the same command, I get an error:

```
.avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

This error is not present if I upload code with the Arduino IDE.

I can see a difference - the Arduino IDE displays this line before the AVRDUDE call:

> Forcing reset using 1200 bps open/close on port /dev/cu.usbmodem1431

How can I make this reset by command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you pretty much wrote the answer yourself.

You need to open a serial connection at 1200 baud to the Arduino and then close the connection. The Arduino will then boot into SAM-BA, and reset itself, and is now ready for a new program.

Comment: I do not understand how arduino will understand to reset just by openning/closing port ?

Comment: Here is something for you to read then, https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/arduinoBoardLeonardo - See "Automatic (Software) Reset and Bootloader Initiation" section

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue on macOS, and I came up with the following Bash script:

```
# Find the Arduino port
ARDUINO_UPLOAD_PORT="$(find /dev/cu.usbmodem* | head -n 1)"

# Reset the Arduino
stty -f "${ARDUINO_UPLOAD_PORT}" 1200

# Wait for it...
while :; do
  sleep 0.5
  [ -c "${ARDUINO_UPLOAD_PORT}" ] && break
done

# ...upload!
avrdude "${OPTIONS[@]}"
```

The `while` loop is the trick! It's going to proceed as soon as the Arduino port is back online.

This is part of a Makefile I wrote for the project [Sesame](https://github.com/gibatronic/sesame).

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo or a MacOS thing. Under Linux `stty` has only an `-F` switch that seems to do what the above `-f` is supposed to do...

Comment: Indeed, at one point in space and time they diverged, macOS tools are BSD and linux ones are GNU:
[Know Your Tools: Linux (GNU) vs. Mac (BSD) Command Line Utilities](https://ponderthebits.com/2017/01/know-your-tools-linux-gnu-vs-mac-bsd-command-line-utilities-grep-strings-sed-and-find/)

Comment: Ha! You are right, FreeBSD man page says `-f`, too: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stty Anyway, good to know and maybe it would be good to point it out in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

For uploading from Windows, I made a bat file wrapper for AVRDUDE.

It identifies the Leonardo COM port with WMI, resets this COM port to 1200 baud with the [MODE](https://ss64.com/nt/mode.html) command, identifies the bootloader COM port and invokes AVRDUDE.

The firmware is supposed to be placed in *firmware.hex*, but it can be changed to be supplied from the command line.

Code is in a GitHub repository, *[Arduino Leonardo Uploader](https://github.com/p1ne/arduino-leonardo-uploader)*

Or below:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption  /format:list ^| find "SparkFun Pro Micro"') do (
    call :resetCOM "%%~J"
)

:continue

:: wmic /format:list strips trailing spaces (at least for path win32_pnpentity)
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption  /format:list ^| find "Arduino Leonardo bootloader"') do (
    call :setCOM "%%~J"
)

:: end main batch
goto :EOF

:resetCOM <WMIC_output_line>
:: sets _COM#=line
setlocal
set "str=%~1"
set "num=%str:*(COM=%"
set "num=%num:)=%"
set port=COM%num%
echo %port%
mode %port%: BAUD=1200 parity=N data=8 stop=1
goto :continue

:setCOM <WMIC_output_line>
:: sets _COM#=line
setlocal
set "str=%~1"
set "num=%str:*(COM=%"
set "num=%num:)=%"
set port=COM%num%
echo %port%
goto :flash

:flash
avrdude -v -C./avrdude.conf -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -P%port% -b57600 -D -V -Uflash:w:./firmware.hex:i
```

Comment: I need to upload my sketch on startup, I am using Arduino UNO, this solution fit me?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I've tried opening and closing the ACM0 port with a Python script at 1200 baud, as someone already mentioned. It didn't work for me. Then I have received half-advice to try toggling [RTS/DTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_(data)#Hardware_flow_control) and that will make autoreset. So in the end I found the solution (at least for me) on Linux Mint 18.2 (Sonya):

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import serial

com = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], 1200)
com.dtr=False
com.close()


python ./reset.py "/dev/ttyACM0"
```

`dmesg` shows me:

```
[21850.047120] cdc_acm 1-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[22093.700327] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 53
[22094.034133] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 54 using xhci_hcd
[22094.175377] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0036
[22094.175381] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[22094.175384] usb 1-1: Product: Arduino Leonardo
[22094.175387] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Arduino LLC
[22094.175964] cdc_acm 1-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Comment: For me,  this (plus waiting 2 seconds) finally got my atmeg32u4 itsy bitsy programming. Whew!

Comment: This also seems to be the way to go for the Arduino Nano Every board.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, in a command prompt, the same solution, slightly different batch file:

It determines the bootloader COM port as well. Note that just *only* the Leonardo to be flashed should be connected!

```
@echo off
echo Upgrade procedure starting.
if %1.==. goto error
set hexfile=%1
set comportA=NONE
set comportB=NONE
if not exist %hexfile% goto error
for /f "usebackq" %%B in (`wmic path Win32_SerialPort Where "Caption LIKE '%%Leonardo%%'" Get DeviceID ^| FIND "COM"`) do set comportA=%%B
if %comportA%==NONE goto nodevice
echo COM port for Arduino device is detected as %comportA%.
echo Reset Arduino into bootloader
mode %comportA%: baud=12 > nul
timeout 2 > nul
for /f "usebackq" %%B in (`wmic path Win32_SerialPort Where "Caption LIKE '%%Leonardo%%'" Get DeviceID ^| FIND "COM"`) do set comportB=%%B
if %comportB%==NONE goto nobldevice
echo COM port for Arduino bootloader device is detected as %comportB%.
echo.
echo Starting AVR Downloader/UploaDEr.....
avrdude -pm32u4 -cavr109 -D -P%comportB% -b57600 -Uflash:w:%hexfile%
goto upgradedone
:nodevice
echo No matching module found, you should connect the module you want to upgrade.
goto end
:nobldevice
echo Reset into bootloader failed, please try again...
goto end
:error
Echo Missing parameter or file, you should provide the full filename of an existing .hex file you want to use.
goto end
:upgradedone
echo.
echo Upgrade done!
:end
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this for Nano-every:
I think the essential elements are:

1. configure appropriate com port at 1200 baud with DTR = ON
2. Turn DTR off.
3. Flash device with correct version of avrdude and avrdude.config. My version came with the installation of my Nano-every device.
   For other boards, it might be different. Lines 1, 2 reset the port and I think this is independent of the board, but change the port number!

c:\windows\system32\mode.com com6: baud=1200 dtr=on

c:\windows\system32\mode.com com6: dtr=off

C:\Users\Ludo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude -CC:\Users\Ludo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega4809 -cjtag2updi -PCOM6 -b115200 -e -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\Ludo\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_385557/sketch_dec11a.ino.hex:i -Ufuse2:w:0x01:m -Ufuse5:w:0xC9:m -Ufuse8:w:0x00:m {upload.extra_files}

Answer (score 1):

Like Ludo answer:

> I use this for Nano-every: I think the essential elements are:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65264449/23110301

**Except** on my machine (Windows10), following gives a kick:

```
c:\> mode.com COM4: baud=1200 dtr=ON  DATA=8
Default to even parity.

Status for device COM4:
-----------------------
    Baud:            1200
    Parity:          Even
    Data Bits:       8
    Stop Bits:       1
    Timeout:         ON
    XON/XOFF:        OFF
    CTS handshaking: OFF
    DSR handshaking: OFF
    DSR sensitivity: OFF
    DTR circuit:     ON
    RTS circuit:     OFF
```

then

```
avrdude -p atmega4809 -c jtag2updi -P COM4 -U flash:r:testDump -b115200 -v
...
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.28s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9651 (probably m4809)
avrdude: reading flash memory:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 7.59s

avrdude: writing output file "testDump"

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FF, H:FF, L:FF)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

In my example I just wanted to take dump (pun intended) of flash to the file. Took me 1/2 day and half night but I am happy as a child.
Thanks to OP and Ludo!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with arduino leonardo.

I want to share my solution for people wanting to solve this problem using Qt.

Here is solution ready to be copy and paste, also taking care of timeout:

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QThread>
#include <QtCore/QElapsedTimer>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>

bool forceResetComPort(const QString& portName)
{
    QSerialPort serial;
    serial.setPortName(portName);
    serial.setBaudRate(1200);

    qDebug() << "Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port ") << portName;
    if(!serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
        return false;

    // This seems optional
    serial.setDataTerminalReady(false);

    qDebug() << "Waiting for the new upload port...";

    QElapsedTimer timeoutWatcher;
    qint64 timeoutMs = 10000;
    bool isPortPresent = true;

    const auto fetchIsPortPresent = [&]() -> bool
    {
        const auto ports = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
        for(const auto& info : ports)
        {
            if(info.portName() == serial.portName())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    timeoutWatcher.start();

    // Wait for port to disconnect
    while(isPortPresent && !timeoutWatcher.hasExpired(timeoutMs))
    {
        isPortPresent = fetchIsPortPresent();

        if(isPortPresent)
            QThread::msleep(1);
    }

    serial.close();

    // Wait for port to reconnect
    while(!isPortPresent && !timeoutWatcher.hasExpired(timeoutMs))
    {
        isPortPresent = fetchIsPortPresent();

        if(!isPortPresent)
            QThread::msleep(1);
    }
 
    return !timeoutWatcher.hasExpired(timeoutMs);
}
```

It is all about timing. I really needed to wait for the serial port to disconnect to close serial.

- Closing too fast didn't have any effect.
- Closing too slow, the usb serial was reconnecting but with a different port name. (For example /dev/ttyACM0 to /dev/ttyACM1).
- It's important to wait for the port to reconnect in my case because I call avrdude in QProcess after.

Here is dmesg:

```sh
[ 8566.623621] cdc_acm 1-8:1.0: failed to set dtr/rts
[ 8566.979697] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[ 8567.133193] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0036, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 8567.133197] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 8567.133199] usb 1-8: Product: Arduino Leonardo
[ 8567.133200] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Arduino LLC
[ 8567.134820] cdc_acm 1-8:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```